# Reload doesn't reload

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function updateimage(){
 $("#fileimg").attr("src","image.jpg");
 $('#fileimg').fadeIn('slow');
}

function updatefiles(){
 $.get('files.php', function(data) {
   $('#files').html(data);
   $('#files').fadeIn('slow');
 });
}
updatefiles();

setTimeout('updateimage()', 5000);
setTimeout('updatefiles()', 5000);
```

Well i have this code to update an image and some text, but it doesn't update... The data doesn't change and the fadein doesn't work.

can y'all help me? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look with FireBug whether an AJAX call is made and what does the server responds. Also check if there are some errors in the console.

Comment: Agree with Darin... verify that you're getting a response from your .get() method.  Also want to suggest using method chaining.  So updateimage() would look like: $( '#fileimg' ).attr().fadeIn() all in one fell swoop.  No reason to spend the resources looking for $( '#fileimg' ) twice.  Grab it once, and do what you need ot do.

Comment: +1 charliegriefer. that is such an great tip. Why it never came to my mind. Now it looks like common sense. I will definitely apply method chaining next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
setTimeout('updateimage()', 5000);
setTimeout('updatefiles()', 5000);
```

You should do this:

```
setTimeout(updateimage, 5000);
setTimeout(updatefiles, 5000);
```